# React not working when bundled with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I did the most bare-bones React implementation possible, and I'm running into problems. When I bundle React, then open up the index.html page, it is completely blank. No console errors, or anything to say I did something wrong.

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('src/client/public/bundle'),
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'style-loader' },
                { loader: 'css-loader' }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
               use: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And my very basic index.js file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hi</h1>,
  document.getElementById('app'),
);
```

When this is bundled, and included in a `<script>` tag, nothing happens. I think this is a react issue because when I externally add `<script>` tags for `react.js` and `react-dom.js` from CDN, the program works as expected.

Am I doing something wrong in terms of bundling react? I would like there to only be one included file (bundle.js). How can I achieve this?

*Edit*

Following Tomasz' suggestion, I installed HtmlWebpackPlugin. Using that, it suddenly works... I'm very confused, as almost nothing has changed. In both, I'm using a `<div id="app"></div>`. Anyway, thanks.

*Edit 2*

I figured it out. I was calling the bundled script like this:
`<script src="bundle.js" />`
rather than:
`<script src="bundle.js"></script>`
meaning it did not execute. It works now!

Comment: Lol, I had the same issue and my error was that I was calling "<sript ..." instead of  "<script ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [html webpack plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin):

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('src/client/public/bundle'),
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                { loader: 'style-loader' },
                { loader: 'css-loader' }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
               use: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
    ]
};
```

It will automatically generate `index.html` file with script tag to your bundle file. I think it should help or at least point to the error.

Comment: this worked. It fixed this issue, and I'm still not sure why. Thanks for the suggestion.